# Entity Framework Stored Procedures vs Generated SQL

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I've used the entity framework in a couple of projects.  In every project, I've used stored procedures mapped to the entities because of the well known benefits of stored procedures - security, maintainability, etc.  However, 99% of the stored procedures are basic CRUD stored procedures.  This seems like it negates one of the major, time saving features of the Entity Framework -- SQL generation.

I've read some of the arguments regarding stored procedures vs. generated SQL from the Entity Framework.  While using CRUD SPs is better for security, and the SQL generated by EF is often more complex than necessary, does it really buy anything in terms of performance or maintainability to use SPs?

Here is what I believe:

- Most of the time, modifying an SP requires updating the data model
  anyway.  So, it isn't buying much in terms of maintainability.
- For web applications, the connection to the database uses a single user ID specific to the application.  So, users don't even have direct database access.  That reduces the security benefit.
- For a small application, the slightly decreased performance from using
  generated SQL probably wouldn't be much of an issue.  For high
  volume, performance critical applications, would EF even be a wise
  choice?  Plus, are the insert / update / delete statements generated
  by EF really that bad?
- Sending every attribute to a stored procedure has it's own performance penalties, whereas the EF generated code only sends the attributes that were actually changed.  When doing updates to large tables, the increased network traffic and overhead of updating all attributes probably negates the performance benefit of stored procedures.

With that said, my specific questions are:

Are my beliefs listed above correct?  Is the idea of always using SPs something that is "old school" now that ORMs are gaining in popularity?  In your experience, which is the better way to go with EF -- mapping SPs for all insert / update / deletes, or using EF generated SQL for CRUD operations and only using SPs for more complex stuff?

Comment: `modifying an SP requires updating the data model anyway` SP's end up significantly increasing the maintenance cost of your application, not just because you have to make every change in at least 5 places (1 SP each for insert, update, and delete, at least one for select, and then also in your entity model), but also because for anything that's not a simple CRUD operation you're hiding application logic outside of your application, and the developer has to bounce back and forth between different IDE's.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think ***always*** using SP's is somewhat old school. I used to code that way, and now do everything I can in EF generated code...and when I have a performance problem, or other special need, I then add back in a strategic SP to solve a particular problem....it doesn't have to be either or - use both.

All my basic CRUD operations are straight EF generated code - my web apps used to have 100's or more of SP's, now a typical one will have a dozen SP's and everything else is done in my C# code....and my productivity has gone WAY up by eliminating those 95% of CRUD stored procs.

Comment: +1 a good, pragmatic approach - I'd probably go this way, too. Use EF as much as possible, but with the knowledge that **if** you need to tweak the last drop of performance out of an `INSERT` statement somewhere, you can - by using a stored proc for it.

Comment: As you said because of the performance issue it's really worth to write a SP, but how about using views (of course instead of a select query in a SP)? I couldn't found anything related to comparison between these two approaches.

Answer (score 12):

Yes your beliefs are absolutely correct. Using stored procedures for data manipulation has meaning mainly if:

- Database follows strict security rules where changing data is allowed only through stored procedures
- You are using views or custom queries for mapping your entities and you need advanced logic in stored procedure to push data back
- You have some advanced logic (related to data) in the procedure for any other reason

Using procedures for pure CUD where non of mentioned cases applies is redundant and it doesn't provide any measurable performance boost except single scenario

- You will use stored procedures for batch / bulk modifications

EF doesn't have bulk / batch functionality so changing 1000 records result in 1000 updates each executed with separate database roundtrip! But such procedures cannot be mapped to entities anyway and must be executed separately via function import (if possible) or directly as `ExecuteStoreCommand` or old ADO.NET (for example if you want to use table valued parameter).

The whole different story can be R in CRUD where stored procedure can get significant performance boost for reading data with your own optimized queries.

Answer (score 6):

If performance is your primary concern, then you should take one of your existing apps that uses EF with SPs, disable the SPs, and benchmark the new version. That's the only way to get an answer perfectly applicable to your situation. You might find that EF no matter what you do isn't fast enough for your performance needs compared to custom code, but outside of very high volume sites I think EF 4.1 is actually pretty reasonable.

From my PoV, EF is a great developer productivity boost. You lose a fair bit of that if you're writing SPs for simple CRUD operations, and for Insert/Update/Delete in particular I really don't see you gaining much in performance because those operations are so straightforward to generate SQL for. There are definitely some Select cases where EF will not do the optimal thing and you can get major performance increases by writing a SP (hierarchical queries using CONNECT BY in Oracle come to mind as an example).

The best way to deal with that type of thing is to write your app letting EF generate the SQL. Benchmark it. Find areas where there's performance issues and write SPs for those. Delete is almost never going to be one of the cases you need to do this.

As you mentioned, the security gain here is somewhat lessened because you should have EF on an Application tier that has its own account for the app anyway, so you can restrict what it does. SPs do give you a bit more control but in typical usage I don't think it matters.

It's an interesting question that doesn't have a truely right or wrong answer. I use EF primarily so that I don't have to write generic CRUD SPs and can instead spend my time working on the more complex cases, so for me I'd say you should write fewer of them. :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree broadly with E.J, but there are a couple of other options. It really boils down to the requirements for the particular system:

- Do you need to get the app developed FAST? - Then use entity framework and its automatic SQL
- Need fine-grained and solid security? - Get onto stored procedures
- Need it to run as fast as possible? - You're probably looking at some happy medium!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion as long as your application/database does not suffer from performance issues and you are mostly using the database for CRUD and accessing it using just one DB user, it is better to use generated SQL. It is faster to develop, more maintainable and the few security or more privacy benefits are not worth it (if the data is not so sensitive). Also the use of model based database access or LINQ disabled the threat from SQL injections.